# Using mutate_at() on a nested dataframe column to generate multiple unnested columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse, purrr

I'm experimenting with `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `purrr`. I have data like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- data_frame(X1 = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 6),
                 X2 = sort(rep(1:6, 4)),
                 ref = sample(1:50, 24),
                 sampl1 = sample(1:50, 24),
                 var2 = sample(1:50, 24),
                 meas3 = sample(1:50, 24))
```

Now `dplyr` is awesome because I can do things like `mutate_at()` to manipulate multiple columns at once. e.g:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-one_of(c("X1", "X2", "ref"))), funs(first = . - ref)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("first")),  funs(second = . *2 ))
```

and `tidyr` allows me nest subsets of the data as sub-tables in a single column:

```
df <- df %>% nest(-X1)
```

and thanks to `purrr` I can summarize these sub-tables while retaining the original data in the nested column:

```
df %>% mutate(mean = map_dbl(data, ~ mean(.x$meas3_first_second)))
```

How can I use `purrr` and `mutate_at()` to generate multiple summary columns (take the means of different (but not all) columns in each nested sub-table)?

In this example I'd like to take the mean of every column with the word "second" in it.I had hoped that this might produce a new nested column which I could then `unnest()` but it does not work.

```
df %>% mutate(mean = map(data, ~ mutate_at(vars(contains("second")),
                                           funs(mean_comp_exp = mean(.)))))
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You forgot to pass the dataset as the first argument of `mutate_at`:  `~mutate_at(.x, vars...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by @aosmith was correct and helpful In addition I realised I needed to use `summarise_at()` and not `mutate_at()` like so:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(mean = map(data, ~ summarise_at(.x, vars(contains("second")),
                                               funs(mean_comp_exp = mean(.) )))) %>%
    unnest(mean)
```